# Bogomolny equation of static Abelian Higgs model when $\lambda$ =1

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, elliptic-equations, gauge-theory

Consider the Abelian Higgs model in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the action,
$$E= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}F_{A}^2+|D_A \phi|^2 + \frac{1}{4}(1-|\phi|^2)^2 dx$$
where $A=A_1dx_1+A_2dx_2$ is a 1-form connection, $\phi=\phi_1+i\phi_2$ is a complex-valued scalar field. $F_A$ is defined to be $\partial_1A_2-\partial_2A_1$ and $D_A=d\phi-iA\phi$.

Bogomolny pointed out that the action can be rewritten as 
$$E= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|(\partial_1 \phi_1+A_1\phi_2)-(\partial_2\phi_2+A_2\phi_1)|^2 +|(\partial_2 \phi_1+A_2\phi_2)+(\partial_1\phi_2-A_1\phi_1)|^2 \\+|F_{A}+\frac{1}{2}(|\phi|^2-1)|^2+F_{A}dx$$

I am trying to do so but failed.

Expressing the term $|D_A \phi|^2$,
$$|D_A \phi|^2=|\partial_i\phi-iA_i\phi|^2=|\partial_i\phi_1+i\partial_i\phi_2-iA_i\phi_1+A_i\phi_2|^2=|\partial_i\phi_1+A_i\phi_2|^2+|\partial_i\phi_2-A_i\phi_1|^2$$
Next I consider
$$F_{A}^2+\frac{1}{4}(1-|\phi|^2)^2=(F_{A}-\frac{1}{2}(1-|\phi|^2))^2+F_{A}-F_{A}|\phi|^2$$
Thus, by combining the term
\begin{align*}
F_{A}^2+|D_A \phi|^2 + \frac{1}{4}(1-|\phi|^2)^2 &=(F_{A}-\frac{1}{2}(1-|\phi|^2))^2+F_{A}-F_{A}|\phi|^2\\
&+|\partial_1\phi_1+A_1\phi_2|^2+|\partial_1\phi_2-A_1\phi_1|^2\\
&+|\partial_2\phi_1+A_2\phi_2|^2+|\partial_2\phi_2-A_2\phi_1|^2\\
&=(F_{A}-\frac{1}{2}(1-|\phi|^2))^2+F_{A}-F_{A}|\phi|^2\\
&+((\partial_1\phi_1+A_1\phi_2)-(\partial_2\phi_2-A_2\phi_1))^2\\
&+((\partial_2\phi_1+A_2\phi_2)+(\partial_1\phi_2-A_1\phi_1))^2\\
&+2(\partial_1\phi_1+A_1\phi_2)(\partial_2\phi_2-A_2\phi_1)\\
&-2(\partial_2\phi_1+A_2\phi_2)(\partial_1\phi_2-A_1\phi_1)
\end{align*}
Therefore, my job is to show that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}2(\partial_1\phi_1+A_1\phi_2)(\partial_2\phi_2-A_2\phi_1)-2(\partial_2\phi_1+A_2\phi_2)(\partial_1\phi_2-A_1\phi_1)-F_{A}|\phi|^2=0$$
I can only simplify the above term to
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\partial_1(|\phi|^2A_2)-\partial_2(|\phi|^2A_1)+2(\partial_2\phi_1\partial_1\phi_2-\partial_1\phi_1\partial_2\phi_2)$$
How can I do this?